# Mosquitto sometimes kills client connections

Tags: ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using mosquitto 1.4.10.

I have a client that publishes multiple messages to the same topic in batches (eg. 50 messages per batch). The client will send each batch every few seconds (eg. every 5 seconds). After 1 or a few batches are sent, on the next batch, suddenly mosquitto will kill the connection to the client.

I've [provided a packet capture](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04pc31sro11slx0/mqtt_filtered.pcap?dl=0) from the machine the broker is running on that shows the behaviour which I'll describe below.

Client: 172.16.0.114
Mosquitto Broker: 10.16.208.139 (port 8883)

The numbers below are the packet numbers in the capture file.

> 1: Client connects to broker
>
> 17?: Client starts publishing first batch of messages
>
> 386: First batch of messages complete
>
> 387: Client starts publishing second batch of messages
>
> 388: Missing packet?
>
> 389: Mosquitto ACKs packet 387
>
> 390: Mosquitto starts spamming TCP DUP ACK packets for 387
>
> 549: Mosquitto stops spamming TCP DUP ACK packets for 387
>
> 550-578: Lots of retransmissions
>
> 784: Second batch of messages complete
>
> 785: Third batch of messages starts
>
> 788: Mosquitto sends FIN ACK, closing the connection (WHY?)
>
> 790-880: Mosquitto responds to remaining messages with RST

The main question is why would mosquitto suddenly close the connection after starting to receiving the 3rd batch of messages. The logs in mosquitto at this point where the 3rd batch starts is here:

```
18:52:24
1491418344: OpenSSL Error: error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init
18:52:24
1491418344: Socket error on client admin, disconnecting.
```

Comment: Seems much much much more likely that this is a client-side or network problem than a Mosquitto problem. Or a problem with system hosting Mosquitto. Have you tried running the client local to Mosquitto, see if that works differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was being caused by a bug in mosquitto that would kill existing SSL connections if another non-SSL connection was attempted. Specifically, the TCP health check performed by the AWS load balancer was sending a small TCP packet which triggered the bug to kill my client's connection.

See issue on the [mosquitto github](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/419).